# Inequality of $p$-norms, is it true for $p<1$

Tags: calculus

Considering the family of $p$-norms:
$$
\vert x \vert^p=(x_1^p+\dots+x_N^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
is it true that for $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$, $\vert x \vert^{p_1} \le \vert x \vert^{p_2}$ whenever $p_1<p_2$ and $p_{1,2}\in[0,+\infty]$?

Or that is only true for $p_{1,2}\in[1,+\infty]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true for $p$ in $[0,1]$ as well. The reason $p<1$ norms don't often appear is that they don't form [metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).

Comment: Thank you for sorting out this little confusion.